# getting plugin to work for multiple items

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm writing a plugin and having difficulty getting it to instantiate for multiple elements.  I've put [[the code](http://jsfiddle.net/ycsas/)] in jsfiddle.  specifically the problem is that the call to .each() is probably failing:

```
$.fn.Image = function (options) {
    return this.each(function () {
        (new $.Image(this, options));
    });
};
```

I took that from having looked at how other plugins are written but I'm not sure I understand it, particularly why the "new" is used and how when called this results in an array:

```
var imgs = $('img').Image();
```

could someone suggest what the right way to do it is?

**-- Edit --**

maybe I'm a little closer.  I tried this:

```
$.fn.Image = function (options) {
    var ret = [];
    this.each(function () {
        ret[ret.length] = $.Image(this, options);
    });
    return ret;
};
```

which at least returns an array of objects, but my call:

```
img.toggle();
```

fails because what's returned is an array of objects (which can be called with .Image())... so I'm guessing what $.fn.Image() needs to return is a single object which somehow stores its elements... and then how to make all the methods iterate?  I don't get it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure what you are after, but something like this?

```
$.fn.Image = function (options) {

    $(this).each(function (i,e) {
        $.fn.Image(e,options);
    });

    this.testing = function(a){
     if (typeof a == "undefined") a = $(this).text();
     alert(a);   
        return this;
    }

    return this;
};

var a = $('ul').Image().addClass('working');
a.testing("sss");
$('ul li:first-child').testing().addClass('working');
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/wEdzY/

Comment: oh... I see.  but the implication here is that every method (like testing) needs to iterate.  in your example .text() knows how to iterate over the elements of $(this) - so if what I wanted to do is toggle all images, the parameter to the method will contain an array that I need to handle.  is there no easier way than to make all methods responsible for iteration?

Comment: @ekkis Only the top-most `$(this).each` is iterating, every other function accepts a single DOM object

Comment: @meagar, that's not what I observe.  I'v simplified his code to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/wEdzY/18/ you can see that the method gets and array and is therefore responsible for iteration

Comment: @ekkis You're doing it wrong. Your jQuery plugin should extends the jQuery object with a single function which returns the jQuery object it was invoked on, so that methods can be chained. When I said "every other function accepts a single DOM object", I mean in the case of `this.testing`, in the above code, which accepts a single DOM element.

Comment: @meagar, `.testing()` has access to `this` (is this the "single DOM object" you refer to?) but inside are multiple DOM elements which `.testing()` needs to operate on (and therefore is responsible for iteration).  what I am misunderstanding here (what am I doing wrong, in your view)?

Comment: @meagar, in simpler language: my intention is to "toggle" the state of a bunch of images with a single call.  from what I see then, the "toggle" method will have to iterate through elements it is passed, and therefore every method I write will need to support iteration

Comment: @Niklas, one thing I don't understand is: how come your solution doesn't recurse ad infinitum?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
return this.each(...)
```

try

```
return $(this).each(...)
```

Comment: no, that will still fail because the value returned is an array of jQuery objects which doesn't have a .toggle() method

Comment: @ekkis No, on both counds: The value returned will be a *single* jQuery object which may select 0 or more elements, and it *will* have a `.toggle` method.

Comment: I misread your reply... so you mean this: http://jsfiddle.net/8zrfc/1/ - but it doesn't work.  I had tried that already.  upon running you should see the checkmark greyed out